# Using multiple links for a single modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Ok, so I'm attempting to put multiple modal links on a single page, but when each one is clicked, the same modal opens up for all the links because they all use #target-content. I really like this specific modal, but is there a way not have the same modal open up based on the code below? Thank you!

HTML

```
<a href="#target-content" id="button">Open A Modal</a>

<div id="target-content">
  <a href="#" class="close"></a>
  <div id="target-inner">
    <h2>Modal Heading</h2>
    <p>Modal Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#target-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

#target-content:target {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}

#target-content #target-inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 48px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  width: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: white;
  color: #34495E;
}

#target-content #target-inner h2 { margin-top: 0; }

#target-content #target-inner code { font-weight: bold; }

#target-content a.close {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #34495E;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

#target-content a.close:hover { opacity: 0.4; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only supposed to use the #id-name once.

Change the name of the id's #target-content, #target-content1 etc..,

You can use the same css styling with a .class-name but #id-names are supposed to be unique.

Comment: That's what I originally had in mind. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't another, easier way around it instead of having to add additional id tags to the CSS coding. Thank you for your response!

Comment: You are welcome, those simple changes - although a little bit of a pain - will do exactly what you want. Thanks :)